# Radial Gradient with Image IOS

Tags: xcode, swift, quartz-2d

I have a lot of different images in feed, that should be looking like this
http://s014.radikal.ru/i327/1603/14/97b12afe691f.png
In Sketch it s done by mask with RadialGradient. So i tried this way, but:

if i add a layer with gradient above, image is not transparent

if i redraw image with Quartz - i get lags and it is not transparent as it should be

I know it should be easy. Really easy. Please, someone - give me a clue! 
Here is my gradient:

```
let colors: [CGFloat] = [ 88/255, 176/255, 113/255, 0.64, 90/255, 125/255, 113/255, 0.17, 88/255, 92/255, 110/255, 0.01]
let gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, [0.0, 0.7, 0.85], 3)
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, center, 10, center, self.size.width/2, .DrawsAfterEndLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `CALayer` the same size as your image. Draw your gradient into an image and install that CGImage as the contents of the layer. Them make the layer the mask of your image view's layer.

Take a look at my development blog entry [ImageViewWithMask](http://wareto.com/imageviewwithmask) for a working example of using mask layers in Swift. (In my example I use a CAShapeLayer to draw a hard-edged mask. You will need to adapt it to use a gradient instead).

You *should be* able to use a CAGradientLayer, but those don't look like they support radial gradients. They have a gradient type property, but the only supported type appears to be Axial, which is silly.